# # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rubocop

I am really stuck in this part:

If i disable `# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize`, then I am getting this error:

```
ruby -v : ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin14]

rubocop -V
0.52.1 (using Parser 2.4.0.2, running on ruby 2.4.2 x86_64-darwin14)


$ rubocop .
Inspecting 7 files
.....W.

Offenses:

recipes/default.rb:13:1: W: Lint/MissingCopEnableDirective: Re-enable Metrics/AbcSize cop with # rubocop:enable after disabling it.
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
^

7 files inspected, 1 offense detected
```

If I enable `rubocop` in the script then getting this:

```
rubocop .
Inspecting 7 files
.....C.

Offenses:

recipes/default.rb:31:1: C: Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for check_tropo_versions is too high. [33.02/20]
def check_tropo_versions ...
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

7 files inspected, 1 offense detected
```

A few lines of my script:

```
# rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize

require 'nokogiri'
Chef.event_handler do
  on :resource_updated do |resource, _action|
    if resource.declared_type.to_s == 'remote_file' && resource.cookbook_name == 'tropo-patch' && resource.recipe_name == 'default'
      puts "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')},#{resource.path},#{resource.source[0]}"
      File.open('/var/log/tropo-patch.log', 'a') { |f| f.write("#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')},#{resource.path},#{resource.source[0]}\n") }
    end
  end
end
```

I cannot disable `rubocop` from global config file, but if it can resolve I will try this as well:

```
Metrics/AbcSize:
  Description: >-
                 A calculated magnitude based on number of assignments,
                 branches, and conditions.
  Reference: 'http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbcMetric'
  Enabled: true
```

Comment: The error says: **enable after disabling it**. Have you tried writing `# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize` *before* the complex code; **and then also writing `# rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize` after the code**? (I.e. directly below that method, *in the same file*.)

Comment: Also, you have not shown the source code for `check_tropo_versions`. Rather than just disabling the style guide for the method, perhaps you could show it in your question and we'll suggest a better way to write the code; thereby making it rubocop-compliant?

Answer (score 6):

What Rubocop is basically complaining about is that it asks you to enable the cop after the method is closed, so the cop can be in effect for other methods of the file. If you disable it on the first line of the file, it will be disable for all methods in that file. Disabling cops for whole files is not a good idea, since you should be explicit and conscious when disabling the cops.

The fix in your case is just simply disabling the cop before your method, and then enable it after.

For example:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize

require 'nokogiri'
Chef.event_handler do
  on :resource_updated do |resource, _action|
    if resource.declared_type.to_s == 'remote_file' && resource.cookbook_name == 'tropo-patch' && resource.recipe_name == 'default'
      puts "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')},#{resource.path},#{resource.source[0]}"
      File.open('/var/log/tropo-patch.log', 'a') { |f| f.write("#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')},#{resource.path},#{resource.source[0]}\n") }
    end
  end
end

# rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize
```

Also, if you need to disable multiple cops, you can enable all of them by using:

```
# rubocop:enable all
```

Hope that helps!

Edit: After looking at Tom Lord's comment on your question, I noticed that you haven't posted the actual method that is breaking the rule of the cop. Still, the solution I provided should work if your put the `disable` and `enable` statements at the correct places. In addition, I second what Tom stated, that if you show us the code we might improve the method and you will not need to disable the cop for the method.

Comment: ...Except that the complex method is actually `check_tropo_versions`; the source of which was not shown in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable a cop for this method only, instead of adding `# rubocop:disable` at the top of the file, just mark your offender like this

```rb
def check_tropo_versions # rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
# ...
```

Answer (score -4):

Use `cookstyle` in place of `rubocop` there. It’s got better defaults for linting cookbook code.